# java list empty when returning from method

Tags: java, list, junit

I have a method that loops through a sorted Array and those sorted List elements to another list called sortedFirstName. Here is that methods code.

```
 public void sortFirstName(String input){
       Collections.sort(fullName, new FirstNameComparator(input)); 

       for(int i = 0;i<fullName.size();i++){
           System.out.println("\n" + fullName.get(i));
           sortedFirstName.add(fullName.get(i)); //adds to list fine

       }
        System.out.println("Sorted First Name" + sortedFirstName);
        //prints desired output, [Jake Paul, Billy Robinson, Charles Princeton, John Paul, Karen Jacobs]
```

FirstName is a List and is instantiated like so - `List<String> fullName = new ArrayList<String>();` and is populated from a method listAllContacts like so :

```
public void listAllContacts(){

        for (Map.Entry<String,Person> entry : contacts.entrySet()) {
         fullName.add(entry.getValue().fullName());
}
        for (String contents : fullName) {                
           System.out.println("\n" + contents);         
      }
    }
```

it is populated by Strings that are a field of an object in a hashmap

from this method, I print the contents of list sortedFirstName list and get the correct output which is commented under the print statement.

I also have this get method that returns that list

```
public List<String> getSortedFirstNames(){
        return this.sortedFirstName;
    }
```

In my Junit class I am calling these methods like so

```
@Test
    public void sortFirst(){
        ad1.sortFirstName("Jake");
        List sorted = ad1.getSortedFirstNames();
        List sortedList = new ArrayList();
        sortedList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Jake Paul", "Billy Robinson", "Charles Princeton", "John Paul", "Karen Jacobs")); //expected output from boostrapped users
        assertEquals(sortedList,sorted);
    }
```

From my test case logic it should be that `List sorted` contains the elements `[Jake Paul, Billy Robinson, Charles Princeton, John Paul, Karen Jacobs]`but when I compare my hardcoded list against `sorted`, it shows as empty. I cannot see an issue as `sortedFirstName`clearly has the elements added to it, Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There are some details missing. For instance, the sortFirstName uses a field called `fullName` which we know nothing about and it might just be empty in your test case.

Comment: When making a [mcve], you should include all code necessary to reproduce the error. That means it should include test setup as well. What is `a1`? How is it setup?

Comment: "new FirstNameComparator(input)", what is its implementation and as f1sh suggested what is the value of "fullName"

Comment: Edited my post guys to hopefully include more useful info, the ``Collections.sort(fullName, new FirstNameComparator(input));`` is just a comparator that subsorts the list for me

Comment: If you want to investigate why a test is failing, you should use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted my mistake. The `listAllContacts`method is needed to actually populate the `fullName` variable. Without the `listAllContacts` method being called it does not populate the `fullName` and in turn cannot populate the `sortedFirstName` list.

Here is my new code:

```
@Test
    public void sortFirst(){
        ad1.listAllContacts();
        ad1.sortFirstName("Jake");
        List sorted = ad1.getSortedFirstNames();
        List sortedList = new ArrayList();
        sortedList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Jake Paul", "Billy Robinson", "Charles Princeton", "John Paul", "Karen Jacobs")); //expected output from boostrapped users
        assertEquals(sortedList,sorted);
    }
```

note the `ad1.listAllContacts();` which fixed my issue. Thanks to all who commented ti help me with this, much appreciated.